# How to get currently installed location of APK

Tags: android

I am developing an application that I need to log to the server the memory location that the application currently resides ie: Internal memory or External storage. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: To be honest I read your question 3x and I still don't get what you really want

Comment: All apps are installed in `data/data` folder but you cant access that folder without root

Comment: Sorry there was a typo error i mean Internal or SD card Edited

Comment: @tyczj There are definitely other places apps can go, and I don't think there's any guarantee that future Android versions will store apps in any particular location.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get your application's APK directory-

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        String installDir =appInfo.sourceDir;
```